# how to fit the table? dont cutting table

Tags: tables, size, fit, xtable

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
% latex table generated in R 4.2.1 by xtable 1.8-4 package
% Tue Sep 13 11:07:50 2022
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rllllllllll}
  \hline
 & Host\_species & Body site & Sex & Time\_point & The\_lowest\_temperature & The\_highest\_temperature & Coast & Sample\_site & Sales\_area & water\_temperature Feb/May \\ 
  \hline
1 & Batillus\_cornutus & gut & female(25) & May(34) & 13(5) & 24(5) & the\_South\_Sea(41) & Geomundo\_Island(29) & Gangneung(17) & 12.5/20.4 \\ 
  2 &  &  & male(39) &  & 16(5) & 22(5) &  &  & Yeosu(12) & 12.5/20.4 \\ 
  3 &  &  &  &  & 18(12) & 28(6), 33(6) &  & Tongyeong\_coast(12) & Tongyeong(12) & 10/17.9 \\ 
  4 &  &  &  &  & 22(6) & 31(6) &  &  &  &  \\ 
  5 &  &  &  &  & 26(6) & 26(6) &  &  &  &  \\ 
  6 &  &  &  & Feb.(30) & -7(18) & 3(11), 5(7) & the\_East\_Sea(23) & Guryongpo(13) & Pohang(13) & 11.3/15 \\ 
  7 &  &  &  &  & -6(6) & 4(12) &  & Ulleungdo\_Island(5) & Ulleungdo\_Island(5) & ./15 \\ 
  8 &  &  &  &  & -5(6) &  &  & Dokdo(5) & Dokdo(5) & ./15 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

i tried but, I coul'd the error..  also l like chage width

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Can you replace underscores with spaces in the column headings?

Answer (score 4):

There are [many methods to fit a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/11604) but all together are unable to fix a very bad design of the table.

People can suggest something about the design, but this is very subjective issue, and without know the work and your read lines our opinions are mainly useless, so the table design is your work and only your work.

Nonetheless, here an approach to fit that table without changing too much content and design:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary,booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{@{}rLLCLcCLLLL@{}}
 \toprule
 
 & \multirow{2}{=}{Host species}
 & \multirow{2}{=}{Body site}
 &  Sex
 & \multirow{2}{=}{Time point}  
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Temperature (\textcelsius{})} 
 & Coast
 & \multirow{2}{=}{Sample\par site} 
 & \multirow{2}{=}{Sales\par area} 
 & \multirow{2}{=}{Water  \textcelsius{} Feb/May} \\\cmidrule{6-7} 
 &  &  &   &  & Lowest  & \mbox{Highest}  &  &  &  &  \\ 

\midrule
1 & {\em Batillus cornutus} & gut & \female\par (25) & May (34) & 13 (5) & 24 (5) & South Sea (41) & Geomundo Island (29) & Gangneung (17) & 12.5/20.4 \\ 
  2 &  &  & \male\par (39) &  & 16 (5) & 22 (5) &  &  & Yeosu (12) & 12.5/20.4 \\ 
  3 &  &  &  &  & 18 (12) & 28 (6), \par 33 (6) &  & Tongyeong coast (12) & Tongyeong (12) & 10/17.9 \\ 
  4 &  &  &  &  & 22 (6) & 31 (6) &  &  &  &  \\ 
  5 &  &  &  &  & 26 (6) & 26 (6) &  &  &  &  \\ 
  6 &  &  &  & Feb. (30) & -7 (18) & 3 (11),  \par 5 (7) & East Sea (23) & Guryongpo (13) & Pohang (13) & 11.3/15 \\ 
  7 &  &  &  &  & -6 (6) & 4 (12) &  & Ulleungdo Island (5) & Ulleungdo Island (5) & ./15 \\ 
  8 &  &  &  &  & -5 (6) &  &  & Dokdo (5) & Dokdo (5) & ./15 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Not `\em`, but `\itshape`

Comment: @egreg Zoological species names are conventionally written in italics although this is not mandatory.  What is really mandatory is a *different* font (Appendix B6 of ICZN). In short, emphasize, but not necessarily italicize. As you perfectly know, if the text is already in italics for forme reason (text quote, caption, etc.),   `{\itshape  Bacillus}` or `\textit{Bacillus}` will not produce any emphasis (wrong) whereas `{\em Bacillus}` or `\emph{Bacillus}` still produce the right result (upright text in this case). Therefore, safer (and shorter).  `:-)`

Comment: thank you , thank you